# How to normalize multiple array of different size in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, normalize

I use set of images for image processing in which each image generates unique code (Freeman chain code). The size of array for each image varies. However the value ranges from 0 to 7. For e.g. First image creates array of 3124 elements. Second image creates array of 1800 elements.
Now for further processing, I need a fixed size of those array. So, is there any way to Normalize it ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a reason why you are getting different sized arrays when applying a chain code algorithm to different images.  This is because the contours that represent each shape **are completely different**.  For example, the letter `C` and `D` will most likely contain chain codes that are of a different length because you are describing a shape as a chain of values from a starting position.  The values ranging from 0-7 simply tell you which direction you need to look next given the current position of where you're looking in the shape.  Usually, chain codes have the following convention:

```
3  2  1
4  x  0
5  6  7
```

0 means to move to the east, 1 means to move north east, 2 means to move north and so on.  Therefore, if we had the following contour:

```
o  o  x 
o
o  o  o
```

With the starting position at `x`, the chain code would be:

```
4  4  6  6  0  0
```

Chain codes encode how we should trace the perimeter of an object given a starting position.  Now, what you are asking is whether or not we can take two different contours with different shapes and represent them using the same number of values that represent their chain code.   You can't because of the varying length of the chain code.

## `tl;dr`

In general, you can't.  The different sized arrays mean that the contours that are represented by those chain codes are of different lengths.  What you are actually asking is whether or not you can represent two different and unrelated contours / chain codes with the same amount of elements.... and the short answer is no.

---

What you need to think about is **why** you want to try and do this?  Are you trying to compare the shapes between different contours?  If you are, then doing chain codes is not the best way to do that due to how sensitive chain codes are with respect to how the contour changes.  Adding the slightest bit of noise would result in an entirely different chain code.

Instead, you should investigate shape similarity measures instead.  An authoritative paper by Remco Veltkamp talks about different shape similarity measures for the purposes of shape retrieval.  See here:  http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~kreve101/asci/smi2001.pdf .  Measures such as the Hausdorff distance, Minkowski distance... or even simple moments are some of the most popular measures that are used.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I agree with your suggestion on selection of freeman chain coding. I would like to apply your suggestion but there is not enough time for me to do so.
What If I use this formula to normalize it? [fcode normalize](http://postimg.org/image/o0u1yzypd/)

Comment: @nick11 - That procedure you showed me assumes that the objects are more or less the same with some slight differences.  The fact that you have two chain codes that are wildly different in length... I wouldn't recommend using chain codes to compare contours.  Unfortunately your time constraint is a setback that is beyond my control.  If you want to properly compare shapes, doing it with chain codes is ill-advised.